# Android Room Query Using AsyncTask in Repository Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-room, android-mvvm

I am trying to query some data saved in room local database using the id. I have received the id from a serialized object and passed it to my view model class which calls the repository to perform the query using the dao.

An asynctask is used to make things async and return the requested value from db. I have made an interface and initialized it in the async task so I can return the result from db but it fails with NPE.

In activity, I have called repository and passed the serialized data like:

```
   public class ViewSessionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private static final String TAG = ViewSessionActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private Sessions sessions; // serialized object from adapter

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_session);

        init();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }

    private void init() {

        // skipped fvid calls

        sessions = (Sessions) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(Constants.SESSION_DETAIL_KEY);
        Log.d(TAG, "Prog id:\t" + sessions.prog_sessionId);

        //error occurs here which leads to async task call in repository
SessionsRepository.getRepository(getApplication()).getSessionByID(sessions.prog_sessionId); 

    }
```

and in repository:

```
    public class SessionsRepository {

    private static final String TAG = SessionsRepository.class.getSimpleName();

    private SessionsDAO dao;
    private static SessionsRepository repository = null;

    private LiveData<List<Sessions>> allSessions;
    private MutableLiveData<Boolean> loadingState;

    private Context context;
    private final SportsDatabase database;

    public SessionsRepository(Application application) {
        database = SportsDatabase.getInstance(application);
        dao = database.sessionsDAO();
        allSessions = dao.getAllSessions();
        loadingState = new MutableLiveData<>();
        context = application.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static SessionsRepository getRepository(Application context){
        if (repository == null){
            repository = new SessionsRepository(context);
        }
        return repository;
    }

    public void fetchSessions() {
        String coachId = new PrefsUtils(context).getCoachId();

        Call<SessionDetails> call = RestClient.getRestInstance().getSessionsService().fetchSessions(coachId);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<SessionDetails>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SessionDetails> call, Response<SessionDetails> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    loadingState.postValue(false); // remove progress
                    SessionDetails details = response.body();
                    List<Sessions> sessions = details.getSessions();
//                    Log.d(TAG, "N/w sesh size:\t" + sessions.size());
                    saveSessions(sessions);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SessionDetails> call, Throwable t) {
                loadingState.postValue(false);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error Fetching Sessions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void saveSessions(List<Sessions> sessions) {
        new SaveSessionsTask(dao).execute(sessions);
    }

    // this method which calls the async task
    public void getSessionByID(String id){
        new FindSessionTask(dao, context).execute(id);
    }

    public LiveData<List<Sessions>> getSavedSessions() {
        return allSessions;
    }

    public class SaveSessionsTask extends AsyncTask<List<Sessions>, Void, Void> {
        private SessionsDAO dao;

        public SaveSessionsTask(SessionsDAO dao) {
            this.dao = dao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(List<Sessions>... lists) {
            dao.addSessions(lists[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class FindSessionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Sessions>{

        private SessionsDAO dao;
        private OnSessionResultCallback callback;

        public FindSessionTask(SessionsDAO dao, Context context) {
            this.dao = dao;
            this.callback = (OnSessionResultCallback) context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Sessions doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Sessions sessions = dao.getSessionById(strings[0]);
            return sessions;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Sessions sessions) {
            super.onPostExecute(sessions);
            Log.d(SessionsRepository.TAG, "Session name:\t" + sessions.session_name);
        }
    }

    // need help in returning the session found from db in onpostexecute method


}
```

dao class:

```
@Dao
public interface SessionsDAO {

    @Insert
    void addSessions(List<Sessions> sessions);

    @Query("select * from sessions")
    LiveData<List<Sessions>> getAllSessions();

    @Query("select * from sessions where prog_sessionId = :id")
    Sessions getSessionById(String id); // here

}
```

and interface callback to receive data in async task on post execute method:

```
    public interface OnSessionResultCallback {
       void onSessionFound(Sessions sessions);
    }
```

Error in logcat:

```
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: sashi.in.ecosports.extras.App cannot be cast to sashi.in.ecosports.interfaces.OnSessionResultCallback
        at sashi.in.ecosports.rest.db.repositories.SessionsRepository$FindSessionTask.<init>(SessionsRepository.java:110)
        at sashi.in.ecosports.rest.db.repositories.SessionsRepository.getSessionByID(SessionsRepository.java:82)
        at sashi.in.ecosports.ui.activities.ViewSessionActivity.init(ViewSessionActivity.java:63)
        at sashi.in.ecosports.ui.activities.ViewSessionActivity.onCreate(ViewSessionActivity.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6671)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
....
```

I was expecting to log out the found session name but instead got NPE. Can someone help me out in executing a room query async, using an entity field as search string to return the entire entity from a list. How does the view model receive the data and is my interface necessary? Thanks.

Comment: Attach your logcat please

Comment: Done, check again. Can you share how to perform find-by-id and find-by-id-and-update queries in room using mvvm architecture?

Comment: You said you're getting `NullPointerException` but in your attached logcat I'm seeing `ClassCastException`. Have you attached it right?

Comment: Oh sorry about that. The NPE comes when I tried to print session.session_name but they're related

Comment: Error is on this line `this.callback = (OnSessionResultCallback) context;`. `context` is application context but it should be a callback.

Comment: How do I fix it pls?

Comment: Can anyone share with me a good resource or example how to query room with id and return entity and after that update that entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're getting NPE when you're trying to print `session.session_name` this means your returned session object was null which can happen:

1. with a bad query (since your select query is fine I'm guessing you're passing a wrong id)
2. when you haven't inserted any record with that id yet (in that case you have to debug your insertion process and check the database to see if insertion occurred right)

To check your database content on the runtime you can easily use [Stetho](https://github.com/facebook/stetho).

Also about the update query with room you can use the built-in `@Update` annotation which finds the passed object by its primary key and updates all columns or use `@Query` annotation to update a specific column(s) like `@Query("UPDATE sessions SET session_name = :newName WHERE prog_sessionId = :id")` which updates `session_name` column with session id of `id`. Below is a sample code:

```
@Dao
public interface SessionsDAO {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM sessions")   // Retrieve all columns saved in sessions table
    LiveData<List<Sessions>> getAllSavedSessions();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE prog_sessionId = :id")   // Retrieve a single session with all columns saved in sessions table
    Sessions findSessionWithId(String id);

    @Query("SELECT session_name FROM sessions WHERE prog_sessionId = :id")   // Retrieve a single session name saved in sessions table
    String getSessionNameWithId(String id);

    @Update   // Update all non-primary columns of a session
    void updateSession(Sessions session);

    @Query("UPDATE sessions SET session_name = :newName")   // Update session_name column of all saved sessions
    void updateAllSessionNamesTo(String newName);

    @Query("UPDATE sessions SET session_name = :newName WHERE prog_sessionId = :id")   // Update session_name column of a session located with its id
    void updateSessionNameTo(String newName, String id);

    @Query("UPDATE sessions SET session_name = :newName AND session_date = :newDate WHERE prog_sessionId = :id")   // Update session_name and session_date column of a session located with its id
    void updateSessionNameAndDateTo(String newName, long newDate, String id);
}
```

In case you need to run queries on a worker thread you can use java executers, here is a simple example for retrieving session name:

```
@Dao
public abstract class SessionsDAO {
    void getSessionNameWithId(final String id, final NameLoadedListener onFinishListener) {
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecuter().submit(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 String name = getSessionNameWithId(id);
                 onFinishListener.onNameLoaded(name);
             }
        });
    }

    @Query("SELECT session_name FROM sessions WHERE prog_sessionId = :id")   // Retrieve a single session name saved in sessions table
    abstract String getSessionNameWithId(String id);

    public interface NameLoadedListener {
        void onNameLoaded(String name);
    }
}
```

And here is an example of updating session name by retrieving the entity and returning the updated one at the end.

```
@Dao
public abstract class SessionsDAO {
    void updateSessionNameWithId(final String id, final String newName, final SessionUpdateListener onFinishListener) {
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecuter().submit(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 updateSessionName(id, newName, onFinishListener);
             }
        });
    }

    @Transaction
    void updateSessionName(String id, String newName, SessionUpdateListener onFinishListener) {
         Sessions session = findSessionWithId(id);
         session.setName(newName);
         updateSession(session);
         onFinishListener.onSessionUpdated(session);
    }

    @Query("SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE prog_sessionId = :id")   // Retrieve a single session with all columns saved in sessions table
    Sessions findSessionWithId(String id);

    @Update   // Update all non-primary columns of a session
    void updateSession(Sessions session);

    public interface SessionUpdateListener {
        void onSessionUpdated(Sessions session);
    }
}
```

Hope you get the memo.

Comment: I have visualized the db using stetho, thanks for the link and good to know it's a great choice. Also, the id is correct as I have logged it out in the init() of activity and it prints same value as in db. Can you share a more detailed generic answer to findById and findByIdAndUpdate queries using room? I'm coming from a MongoDB background please. Thank you

Comment: @DarthPlagueris you're welcome, see my updated answer.

Comment: Yes I understand this part but the issue sir is in the async part of it as queries can't be run on the main thread. Can you help out with an async task for findbyid and return result? Thank you

Comment: I have posted a simple example for retrieving the session name, updating is also the same.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. I'll read up on executors but what about retrieving an entire entity then fetch the fields from the entity then updating the entity after setting new values to it? How do I return the entity and consume in viewmodel or activity/fragment ui?

Comment: You need to return the updated entity or the old one? To update the UI.

Comment: What is the difference between the dao using abstract class and the one with an interface? I can't write method bodies in interface

Comment: Which dao will be used in the database creator file, the abstract class or the interface pls?

Comment: There's no deference for Room, cause it looks for unimplemented methods to implement. The deference works for you since you can have a method with body on an abstract class but not in an interface.

Comment: So which one should I go for? I have put all db files in same package so I can't put the two together due to name conflicts and renaming the abstract class may not work

Comment: There's no need to have two identical files in same package. Why don't you put all DAO operation methods in one abstract class and use abstract prefix on the ones Room needs to implement? Also for updating entity check my updated answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, where should I use the @abstract? I'm guessing I'll have to implement the interface in activity or fragment to get the result directly or should I do it in viewmodel using live data?

Comment: Thanks, I'll be going with one class and making all my daos as abstract classes

Comment: abstract prefix in dao classes marks method as a needs-to-implement method for Room to implement, you don't have to implement them anywhere, Room does it for you since it needs to work with database. As I said using an abstract class instead of an interface helps you to have a body for a method you don't need room to implement it. In our case running an abstract (database operation) method on worker thread forced us to declare a method and use Java executers in it and run the abstract db method. u can declare all db operation methods like `abstract Session get()` to force Room to implement it.

Comment: After much deliberation on this problem, I have decided to continue using interfaces as my dao class. There's very little time for me to switch up everything and also cos the results interface was throwing errors still. Thank you sir, for your time and effort. I will accept your answer and hope for more help from you.